# Why would a switched outlet wire be wired through a receptacle with no exposed ends?

Tags: electrical

My living room has a dimmer switch that appeared to not be hooked up to anything - the circuit has no lights on it and the switch didn't seem to control any outlets.

I started pulling out outlets on the circuit to figure out where the switch's red wire goes. On the outlet nearest the switch, I saw two red wires tied together with two black wires, with a fifth black wire pig tailed to the outlet:

[image: first outlet wiring]

This explained why the switch didn't do anything: the switch wire was tied hot at the outlet. When I saw *two* red wires in this box, though, I assumed more outlets were connected to the switch.

I pulled out the remaining two outlets on the circuit. One outlet was completely standard with hot and neutral wires only. The last outlet, though, had a red wire going into the box that *immediately left the box* without exposing connections:

[image: second outlet wiring]

I don't understand the wiring in this box. Why would the switch wire be ran this way? There are no other outlets or lights on this circuit, so where is the wire going after it enters this receptacle's box? Do I need to wire the two red wires together at the first outlet, or can I just plug the wire coming from the switch directly into the split outlet?

Comment: Take the picture again and light the inside of the box so we can see in there.;

Comment: Won't be able to get another picture until tomorrow. For the second picture, the red wire seems to come out of the top right of the box and then immediately leave the hole on the right side. Going into that same hole are neutral + ground wires that are pig tailed to the neutral/grounds coming out of the top left/top right of the box.

Comment: That last picture looks like the wire goes out a jagged hole in the side of the box. That's definitely not up to code, and also unsafe because the wire insulation can chafe against the rough edge. Unfortunately, I've seen this in other places before, and fixing it can sometimes be difficult.

Comment: But where could the wire run to through the jagged hole? There are no other outlets or lights on this circuit

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the person who performed that wiring atrocity, no one out here on the internet is going to know. And you don't need to do anything except cap off unused wire ends and let it be. There is no reasonable basis for assuming anything about those mystery wires.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the 2nd photo.  I believe there are 4 separate cables entering that box, where 2 of them have been hacked through the side via illegal modification.

In those 2 cables on the side, only 3 wires are visible in the photo.  There should be more than that.

Make sure the power is off to all 4 cables.  Poke around in that side hole with needle nose plyers and see if you can find the rest of the wires.  If you do find them, this will make it much easier to identify the purpose of each cable.

If you suspect abandoned old work then one or more of those cables might be detached inside the wall and should be capped off when identified.

As for the 2 red wires in the first photo, go ahead and separate them from the black wires.  Only one of those red wires goes to the switch.  You might need to (carefully) restore power and test the wires while the switch is on.

Answer (score -1):

I took another look at the wall next to the second outlet in the picture and it's fairly obvious now that I am looking for it that there used to be a receptacle here that was patched over:

[image: wall next to outlet]

You can vaguely see the outline of a box and screw:
[image: receptacle outline]

I can only assume at some point someone installed a second receptacle here off of the red wire. It was probably hastily removed before putting the house for sale since it clearly would violate code.

Comment: The code violation would be junctions (or wire ends) in that box permanently hidden behind the drywall. If there's still a box there with wires in it, you should really expose the box and put a blank cover plate over it. You can paint/wallpaper the cover plate to match, but you must _not_ bury the box behind drywall (even if _you_ didn't do it, you're responsible for fixing it up again). This should have been caught by your presale inspection...